# React passing list to state from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I have two commponents. Map and LfMap.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { LfMap } from '../../components/Localisation/LfMap';


export class Map extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            dev: [],
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("URL")
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(pas => this.setState({dev: pas}));
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <LfMap list={this.state.dev}/>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

import React from 'react';
import { Map, CircleMarker, TileLayer, Polyline} from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import Control from 'react-leaflet-control';

class LfMap extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            devices: this.props.list,
        }
    }

    render() {

        return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <Map
            style={{ height: "480px", width: "100%" }}
            zoom={12}
            center={[22.22, 21.00]}
            >
                <TileLayer url="http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
            </Map>
        </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export { LfMap };
```

And I'm passing a prop list to LfMap with list of my objects.

But when I'm trying to console.log(this.state.devices) it shows Undefined but it should console my list of objets which i fetched in other component. Why it's happening?

Comment: Inside yout Map components the this,state,dev is populated correctly? Could you console.log it?

Comment: Where have you put your console.log(this.state.devices)?

Comment: Yes, in Map i can console it correctly. When i try to console it in constructor of LfMap it works, but when i try to console it for example in render method i doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why set state = props ? is an **anti-pattern**, you should keep using this.prop.list in the other component.

Do this:

```
console.log(this.props.list)
```

it will print [], and then when the results come it will print the full array.

When you need to use this array always use this.props.list.

***Based in your comment here is how you give solution to that:***
At the parent you add a function

```
listUpdate(newList){
 this.setState({
    list: newList
})
}
```

and then you pass this function to the child

```
 <LfMap list={this.state.dev} listUpdate={this.listUpdate}/>
```

when you need to update it you need to call this.props.listUpdate.
Always update the props :) that's where the reference is, this is the pattern you should follow.

Comment: Because i need to modify this array, for example deleting some of objects and i need update array dynamically all the time

Comment: done I updated my answer for your needs :) always have a new function and it will fix everything :)
Feel free to upvote + mark as the accepted answer

Comment: Thank you! But how can I resolve me problem with not anti-pattern  soultion?

Comment: just use my solution, delete the state=this.props.list, everytime you need to print you can do this.props.map       and when to update this.props.listUpdate (RECHECKK MY ANSWER I ALREADY EDITED IT)

Comment: Yes I see it! :) But you told that it is not correct for react and it's anti-patern. So how could I do it without anti-pattern solution?

Comment: ahahahhh :P i said anti pattern is the thing you did before , not my new answer :) sorry for the confusion, I will delete it